# Using CCM with Opscenter and manual agent installation

Tags: cassandra, opscenter, ccm

I installed with CCM a 4 nodes local cluster (127.0.0.1-127.0.0.4).

```
ccm create -v 2.1.5 -n 4 gp
```

I'm trying to manually install the agents to use OpsCenter (5.2.3.2015121015). I started the OpsCenter removing the JMX port, so the configuration is

```
[jmx]
username = 
password = 

[agents]

[cassandra]
username = 
seed_hosts = 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4
password = 
cql_port = 9042
```

I've configured all the four agents. For example *agent3* configuration is

```
[Giampaolo]: ~/opscenter/> cat agent3/conf/address.yaml 
stomp_interface: "127.0.0.1"

agent_rpc_interface: 127.0.0.3
jmx_host: 127.0.0.3
jmx_port: 7300
```

I started the OpsCenter in foreground and I have this error. As I start *agent4* I have this error:

```
2015-12-30 17:46:21+0100 [gp] ERROR: The state of the following nodes could not be determined, most likely due to agents on those nodes not being properly connected: [<Node 127.0.0.4='4611686018427387904'>, <Node 127.0.0.3='0'>, <Node 127.0.0.2='-4611686018427387904'>, <Node 127.0.0.1='-9223372036854775808'>]
2015-12-30 17:46:24+0100 [gp]  INFO: Agent for ip 127.0.0.4 is version None
2015-12-30 17:46:24+0100 [gp]  INFO: Agent for ip 127.0.0.4 is version u'5.2.3'
2015-12-30 17:46:37+0100 [gp]  INFO: Nodes without agents: 127.0.0.3, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.1
2015-12-30 17:46:51+0100 [gp] ERROR: The state of the following nodes could not be determined, most likely due to agents on those nodes not being properly connected: [<Node 127.0.0.4='4611686018427387904'>, <Node 127.0.0.3='0'>, <Node 127.0.0.2='-4611686018427387904'>, <Node 127.0.0.1='-9223372036854775808'>]
```

I'm a bit confused by the fact that first log tells me that an agent was found for 4, while after a bit I have the error on console.

The agent 4 log tells me at the beginning that there are no errors (only INFO severity):

```
[Giampaolo]: ~/opscenter/>agent4/bin/datastax-agent -f 
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,399 Loading conf files: ./conf/address.yaml
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,461 Java vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_40
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,462 DataStax Agent version: 5.2.3
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,489 Default config values: {:cassandra_port 9042, :rollups300_ttl 2419200, :finished-request-cache-size 100, :settings_cf "settings", :agent_rpc_interface "127.0.0.4", :restore_req_update_period 60, :my_channel_prefix "/agent", :poll_period 60, :monitored_cassandra_pass "*REDACTED*", :thrift_conn_timeout 10000, :cassandra_pass "*REDACTED*", :rollups60_ttl 604800, :stomp_port 61620, :shorttime_interval 10, :longtime_interval 300, :max-seconds-to-sleep 25, :private-conf-props {:cassandra.yaml #{"broadcast_address" "rpc_address" "broadcast_rpc_address" "listen_address" "initial_token"}, :cassandra-rackdc.properties #{}}, :thrift_port 9160, :agent-conf-group "global-cluster-agent-group", :jmx_host "127.0.0.4", :ec2_metadata_api_host "169.254.169.254", :metrics_enabled 1, :async_queue_size 5000, :backup_staging_dir nil, :remote_verify_max 30000, :disk_usage_update_period 60, :throttle-bytes-per-second 500000, :rollups7200_ttl 31536000, :trace_delay 300, :remote_backup_retries 3, :cassandra_user "*REDACTED*", :ssl_keystore nil, :rollup_snapshot_period 300, :is_package false, :monitor_command "/usr/share/datastax-agent/bin/datastax_agent_monitor", :thrift_socket_timeout 5000, :remote_verify_initial_delay 1000, :cassandra_log_location "/var/log/cassandra/system.log", :restore_on_transfer_failure false, :ssl_keystore_password "*REDACTED*", :tmp_dir "/var/lib/datastax-agent/tmp/", :monitored_thrift_port 9160, :config_md5 nil, :jmx_port 7400, :jmx_metrics_threadpool_size 4, :use_ssl 0, :max_pending_repairs 5, :rollups86400_ttl 0, :monitored_cassandra_user "*REDACTED*", :nodedetails_threadpool_size 3, :api_port 61621, :monitored_ssl_keystore nil, :slow_query_fetch_size 2000, :kerberos_service nil, :backup_file_queue_max 10000, :jmx_thread_pool_size 5, :production 1, :monitored_cassandra_port 9042, :runs_sudo 1, :max_file_transfer_attempts 30, :config_encryption_active false, :running-request-cache-size 500, :monitored_ssl_keystore_password "*REDACTED*", :stomp_interface "127.0.0.1", :storage_keyspace "OpsCenter", :hosts ["127.0.0.1"], :rollup_snapshot_threshold 300, :jmx_retry_timeout 30, :unthrottled-default 10000000000, :multipart-chunk-size 5000000, :remote_backup_retry_delay 5000, :sstableloader_max_heap_size nil, :jmx_operations_pool_size 4, :slow_query_refresh 5, :remote_backup_timeout 1000, :slow_query_ignore ["OpsCenter" "dse_perf"], :max_reconnect_time 15000, :seconds-to-read-kill-channel 0.005, :slow_query_past 3600000, :realtime_interval 5, :pdps_ttl 259200}
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,492 Waiting for the config from OpsCenter
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,493 Attempting to determine Cassandra's broadcast address through JMX
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,494 Starting Stomp
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:20,495 Starting up agent communcation with OpsCenter.
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,595 Reconnecting to a backup OpsCenter instance
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,597 SSL communication is disabled
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,597 Creating stomp connection to 127.0.0.1:61620
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,603 Reconnecting in 0s.
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,608 Connected to 127.0.0.1:61620
  INFO [main] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,609 Starting Jetty server: {:join? false, :ssl? false, :host "127.0.0.4", :port 61621}
  INFO [Initialization] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,608 Sleeping for 2s before trying to determine IP over JMX again
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,681 Got new config from OpsCenter [note values in address.yaml override those from OpsCenter]: {:cassandra_port 9042, :rollups300_ttl 2419200, :destinations [], :restore_req_update_period 1, :monitored_cassandra_pass "*REDACTED*", :cassandra_pass "*REDACTED*", :cassandra_rpc_interface "127.0.0.4", :rollups60_ttl 604800, :jmx_pass "*REDACTED*", :thrift_port 9160, :ec2_metadata_api_host "169.254.169.254", :metrics_enabled 1, :backup_staging_dir "", :rollups7200_ttl 31536000, :cassandra_user "*REDACTED*", :jmx_user "*REDACTED*", :metrics_ignored_column_families "", :cassandra_log_location "/var/log/cassandra/system.log", :monitored_thrift_port 9160, :config_md5 "e78e9aaea4de0b15ec94b11c6b2788d5", :provisioning 0, :use_ssl 0, :max_pending_repairs 5, :rollups86400_ttl -1, :monitored_cassandra_user "*REDACTED*", :api_port "61621", :monitored_cassandra_port 9042, :storage_keyspace "OpsCenter", :hosts ["127.0.0.4"], :metrics_ignored_solr_cores "", :metrics_ignored_keyspaces "system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter", :rollup_subscriptions [], :jmx_operations_pool_size 4, :cassandra_install_location ""}
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,693 Couldn't get broadcast address, will retry in five seconds.
  INFO [Jetty] 2015-12-30 17:46:24,715 Jetty server started
  INFO [Initialization] 2015-12-30 17:46:26,615 Sleeping for 4s before trying to determine IP over JMX again
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-12-30 17:46:29,696 Couldn't get broadcast address, will retry in five seconds.
```

however after a while:

```
 INFO [qtp153482676-24] 2015-12-30 17:49:07,057 HTTP: :get /cassandra/conf {:private_props "True"} - 500
 ERROR [qtp153482676-24] 2015-12-30 17:49:09,084 Unhandled route Exception (:bad-permissions): Unable to locate the cassandra.yaml configuration file. If your configuration file is not located with the Cassandra install, please set the 'conf_location' option in the Cassandra section of the OpsCenter cluster configuration file and restart opscenterd. Checked the following locations: /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml, /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml, /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
  INFO [qtp153482676-24] 2015-12-30 17:49:09,085 HTTP: :get /cassandra/conf {:private_props "True"} - 500
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-12-30 17:49:09,845 Couldn't get broadcast address, will retry in five seconds.
 ERROR [qtp153482676-19] 2015-12-30 17:49:11,102 Unhandled route Exception (:bad-permissions): Unable to locate the cassandra.yaml configuration file. If your configuration file is not located with the Cassandra install, please set the 'conf_location' option in the Cassandra section of the OpsCenter cluster configuration file and restart opscenterd. Checked the following locations: /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml, /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml, /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

I've tried after this to add the other agents, but I got strange results. Something like two agents are going to the same C* node so I've stopped trying before I think that this error causes the others.

**Questions:**

1. What is the error is OpsCenter log?
2. Is it somehow related to error on agent log?
3. Am I missing something on configuration (are more details needed?)
4. Why OpsCenter complains about a missing cassandra.yaml file? Shouldn't it deployable on any host even if it has not a local C* installation?

Thanks in advance

**edit**
I added some additional information:

```
 [Giampaolo]: ~/> netstat -an | grep 7400
 tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.7400         *.*                    LISTEN
```

should it be `127.0.0.4`?

This is (part of ) configuration for node4:

```
[Giampaolo]: ~/.ccm/gp/node4/conf/> cat cassandra.yaml | grep 127
listen_address: 127.0.0.4
rpc_address: 127.0.0.4
  - seeds: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4
```

and this is `address.yaml` for node4:

```
[Giampaolo]: ~/opscenter/agent4/conf/> cat address.yaml 
stomp_interface: "127.0.0.1"

agent_rpc_interface: 127.0.0.4
jmx_host: 127.0.0.4
jmx_port: 7400

alias: "the4node"
```

Comment: opscenter uses a cassandra keyspace to store all of its variables, so it does require a c* installation.

Comment: In fact, it creates a new keyspace on first node of the cluster created with CCM. Does it requires another installation?

Comment: the agent collects the location of the cassandra.yaml from jmx. It also uses that to get the broadcast address to connect to. I think if jmx fails you would expect all those errors. Can you verify node4's jmx connection is listening appropriately with ```netstat -anp | grep 7400```? It should show a 127.0.0.4. Also just to double check, can you post the node4's address.yaml?

Comment: side note: would help in your ui if you add an alias to each address.yaml. ie node1 can have a ```alias: node1```. Otherwise the ui will apply the dns resolved "localhost" to each which can be very confusing.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisLohfink for your indication. This is what I gathered so far. As you expected something's wrong on 4. However all 4 nodes give me the same result, ie 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration was ok, except for a little detail. For every agent, in `address.yaml` file, `localhost` must be used instead of `127.0.0.1` in `jmx_host`parameter as suggested in [cassandra user mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg45392.html)